# I am trying to download multple image as a zip file but getting error using laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to download multiple images as a zip file but unfortunately, I am getting errors using laravel 7 please help me how can I resolve that? thanks.

**please check error here**

https://flareapp.io/share/yPayYNYP#F49

**controller**

```
public function dowload($id)
    {


        $inbox = Inbox::find($id);

        $zip = new \ZipArchive;
        $folderName = $inbox->id . '-' . str_replace(' ', '-', $inbox->order_name);
        $fileName    =  $folderName . '.zip';


        if ($zip->open(($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

            $url = config('yourstitchart.file_url');

            $inboxFiles = json_decode(Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file);
            
            $files = [];
            foreach ($inboxFiles as $i => $value) {
                $files[$i] = ($url . $value);
            }

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($file);
                $zip->addFile($file, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }

            $zip->close();
        }
        return response()->download($fileName);
    }
```

Comment: looks like your if condition is failing. check your file permissions

Comment: which file need to check ?

Comment: looks like the folder of the same php file

Comment: I did not understand.